# How to add a new field to the default user model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to add a new field to default Django user. I created a AbstractUser inherited model and added to the settings.py but I getting this error:

> ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy
> reference to 'fdaconfig.customuser', but app 'fdaconfig' doesn't
> provide model 'customuser'. The field fdaconfig.Dataset.user was
> declared with a lazy reference to 'fdaconfig.customuser', but app
> 'fdaconfig' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
user_info = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'fdaconfig.CustomUser'
```

Note: I can not delete database

Comment: If you can not delete the database and can not delete the already existing migration history it will be a long way to go: [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). The problem is, that the first migration has to define the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` otherwise dependency issues will arise.

Comment: if your database model contain some record then provide default value to user_info otherwise provide it to null=true and blank=True